# Integer Quantum Hall Effect: How to show that the circumference of electron orbit is an integer multiple of wavelength?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-hall-effect

Here is my working so far:

$$\frac{mv^2}r = qvB$$
$$\frac{mv}r = qB$$
$$r = \frac{mv}{qB}$$
$$r = \frac{\frac{h}\lambda}{qB}$$
$$r = \frac{h}{q\lambda B}$$
$$2\pi r = \frac{2\pi h}{q\lambda^2 B}\lambda$$

where $\frac{2\pi h}{q\lambda^2 B}$ is an integer.

However, with the data I have been given, this is not resulting in integer values. I have tried other starting points, but none of them show any promising signs of success. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to show that, for the 'plateau' values of B (magnetic field strength), the circumference is an integer multiple of the wavelength?